# Why does no-one notice the large population of Fae in Lost Girl?

Tags: lost-girl

Bo seems to be told a couple of times that there are a whole range of different Fae types, and in *The Mourning After*, Saskia mentions that that there are a number of types of succubus.  Given that there must be a number of each type, this makes for a pretty huge population of Fae.

So why does no-one notice all of these Fae, all of the killing, all of the deaths? I realise that Dyson works hard to keep them hidden, but it seems that with all of these Fae around, with all of the activity that they pursue, why does no-one at all see and remember anything?

**Please avoid spoilers (or use the spoiler markup) from any episodes after season 1, *The Mourning After*.**

Comment: Honestly, it’s because it is filmed in the GTA. We see every ethnicity here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is that, over the centuries/millenia, humans *have* noticed the Fae. They've even given them names. But most people most of the time believe them to be creatures of legend or story: not real, made up, imaginary. And the Fae encourage this belief to the best of their ability.

A lot of the Fae can pass as humans. Improbably short or impossibly sexy humans, as the case may be, but still humans. The Fae leadership does its best to disguise most of their kills as plain old ordinary run-of-the-mill murders or accidents, which any largish city of humans will always have. Both Light and Dark Fae prohibit revealing the Fae to humans: a Fae can't even tell his or her spouse. And if all else fails, the Fae always have the old trick of telling the whole truth, knowing it's so preposterous that nobody will believe them.

Answer (score 2):

Both factions have representatives dedicated to keeping fae kills hidden, and it's in everybody's interest to be quite discreet about it. A lot of them *can* feed non-fatally, or in ways that make the injuries appear self inflicted or deaths of natural causes, and some have abilities that can affect human perception.

It's also been suggested that a lot of fae are in positions of wealth or power, so they presumably have a lot of influence in the workings of the human world - so human populations are basically semi-free range beef herds, in their eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Trick answered this question early in s.1 when Bo noted that she had never heard of many kinds of fae before, replying "well, if you had, we wouldn't have been doing our job." The fae, beyond Dyson, work hard to keep a low profile or at least keep out of view of humans, which is a major reason they keep to themselves and associate only with other fae.